# iReport/jasperReports how can i check in xml data source if node exsicts

Tags: java, jasper-reports, expression

i new to iReport , my question is in the expression editor , how can i build expression that   checks if xml node
extincts and base on that print string
i have this expression that returns me null in the result :

```
( $F{root_customer}.isEmpty() ? "Entity name:" :"Customer id:" )
```

the root_customer does not exsict in the xml

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the following lines in your expression.

```
( $F{root_customer} == null ? "Entity name:" + $F{someField}  
    :"Customer id:" +  + $F{root_customer})
```